# how to avoid devise_invitable from sending a confirmation email?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-confirmable, devise-invitable

from the docs i think it should to not send a confirmation email, but it is doing it.

Here's my setup for the invitable action:

```
class Users::InvitationsController < Devise::InvitationsController

def multiple_create
    if params[:multiple_emails].blank?
        build_resource
        render :new, notice: "something went wrong"
    else
        params[:multiple_emails].each do |email|
            User.invite!({email: email}, current_user) # current_user will be set as invited_by
        end
        if current_user.errors.empty?
            set_flash_message :notice, :send_instructions, :email => params[:multiple_emails]
            respond_with current_user, :location => after_invite_path_for(current_user)
        else
            respond_with_navigational(current_user) { render :new }
        end
    end
end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the cases, where you have to use `:confirmable` for user registration and want to avoid sending confirmation letters with invitation:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  after_create :skip_confirmation_notification!, unless: Proc.new { self.invitation_token.nil? }
end
```

Comment: `:skip_confirmation!` if you don't want any confirmation logic to be applied to this user. `:skip_confirmation_notification!` will disable letters but still force user to confirm email before allowing him to sign in

Answer (score -1):

To avoid devise confirmation mail, you have to exclude `:confirmable` option from the User model.

For example, change:

```
 class User  
   devise :registerable, :confirmable
 end
```

To:

```
 class User  
   devise :registerable
 end
```

Comment: but what if you want to confirm users who sign up without an invitation?

Answer (score -3):

The documentation at [devise_invitable repo on github](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable) are very clear on how to skip sending the invitation email. Look at the second code snippet under **Usage**, which is preceded by this text:

> If you want to create the invitation but not send it, you can set
>   skip_invitation to true.

Comment: I added an answer yesterday, I don't know where it is! I want it to skip the confirmation email, not the invitation one. I hacked into the invite! method and added self.skip_confirmation!